# How to manual convert `BGR` image to `grayscale` (Python OpenCV)?

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, opencv

I want to manually convert a RGB image to Grayscale image.
What I want to know is how to get the Red/Blue/Green values of a RGB pixel ?

```
img = cv2.imread("images/penguins.jpg",0)
grey = img
for i in range(0,grey.shape[0]-1):
    for j in range(0,grey.shape[1]-1):
        img[i,j]=[ ]
```

I dont know what to do next

Thanks,
Sorry for my bad english

Comment: In what kind of data structure are your RGB values?

Comment: Python OpenCV , or maybe I should use some libs ?

Comment: That is not a data structure... how do you read the rgb values? Show us code!

Comment: oh sorry, i'm using an array

Comment: Please show us code!

Comment: i've show/edit it

Comment: Please correctly indent your code.

Comment: like this ? sorry :(

Comment: No, the code for the second for loop also need to be indented.

Comment: oh i see, okeyy

Comment: And what data structure is img (exactly). Please post example of the first 4 pixels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gray formular:

> gray =  0.21 R + 0.72 G + 0.07 B

Prefer to use matrix multiply, other than loop. Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# 2018.01.22 18:55:20 CST
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

## Read as BGR
img = cv2.imread("test.png")

## (1) Loop to calculate
ts = time.time()
H,W = img.shape[:2]
gray = np.zeros((H,W), np.uint8)
for i in range(H):
    for j in range(W):
        gray[i,j] = np.clip(0.07 * img[i,j,0]  + 0.72 * img[i,j,1] + 0.21 * img[i,j,2], 0, 255)

t = (time.time() -ts)
print("Loop: {:} ms".format(t*1000))

## (2) matrix multiply
ts = time.time()
w = np.array([[[ 0.07, 0.72,  0.21]]])
gray2 = cv2.convertScaleAbs(np.sum(img*w, axis=2))
t = (time.time() -ts)
print("Loop: {:} ms".format(t*1000))

## (3) display
cv2.imshow("img", img)
cv2.imshow("gray", gray)
cv2.imshow("gray2", gray2)
cv2.waitKey()
```

---

Time costing:

```
Loop: 6294.47340965271 ms
Loop: 14.13726806640625 ms
```

[image]

Comment: Oh thank you very much it's very help me :)) .. Both is work well but I use the loop one because it's more easy to understand.. Thank you very much :)